# Networkstream small vs. big buffer size

Tags: c#, networking

I have the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assets.SomeProject.Scripts.Common
{
    public class NetworkClient
    {
        #region Private Properties
        private const int port = 2525;
        //private static string server = "192.168.0.22";
        private static string server = "192.168.0.173";
        #endregion

        #region Public Properties
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        public static async Task<byte[]> SendReceiveData(byte[] data)
        {

            // Create a TcpClient.
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            // Send the message to the connected TcpServer.
            await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);


            // get response
            using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    memstream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                while (stream.DataAvailable);
                byte[] newData = memstream.ToArray();

                // Close everything.
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();

                sw.Stop();

                TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;
                string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
                DebugInformation.Instance.AppendDebugTextInNewLine("RecTime " + elapsedTime);

                return newData;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The following is happening here:

- I send data to another device
- On that device runs a python script which does some computation with the data
- The device sends back results as soon as it's done.
- After receiving the result, this class is immediately used to send another request with new data.
- During runtime, due to the nature of the computation, the response will get bigger and bigger with each request.

**Here is the problem:**
I started choosing a relatively small buffer size as given in the code above of 4kb. The problem with that is that receiving the response is extremely slow (several seconds, as soon as we approach a response size of around a mb).
Increasing the buffer size to an arbitrary big amount will increase the transfer speed a lot. However, for some reason, after a few transmissions, my response is missing some, which results in errors. (The python program on the other device tracks the length of the response as well, so I can compare if the correct amount of bytes was sent).

**The question(s):**
Is my approach to receive the data fundamentally wrong? Why are using small buffer sizes so slow, while bigger ones are faulty - what to do about that?

Comment: `DataAvailable` indicates whether there is unread data in the stream. But it doesn't account for the fact that the data may not have arrived yet. For instance, imagine the python script sends 8K of data in two 4K chunks. You read the first one, then `DataAvailable` will be false because the second one has not arrived yet.

Comment: @KevinGosse, ok cool..so is there a way to check if all data has arrived? Or do I, for example, have to send the length of the whole response as additional information in the first few bytes and loop until I get the expected amount?

Comment: Yes, the usual solution is to first send the length, then the actual content

Comment: OK, thank you - that clears things up. Is there a actually a 'good practice' value for the buffer size, or doesn't it matter?

Comment: If you send length first, in say 4 bytes, then your buffer will be 4 bytes first. After you got length your next buffer will be of that length to receive actual data

Comment: Another important point - `ReadAsync` might read less than `buffer.Length`. That's why it returns a value - `bytesRead` in your case. You should read until you actually read all bytes you need (as per above). Checking `DataAvailable` is not needed.

Comment: As noted above, there are multiple issues with the code. The most problematic appears to be your use of `DataAvailable`. However, it's also important to do your own handling of segmenting within the byte stream that is a TCP connection, and to properly handle `0` as a return value for a read operation. See duplicate, and numbers of other sources that discussion correct handling of TCP. Note that if you are using `TcpClient` and just want to copy _all_ data sent start to finish to a new `Stream` object, you can just use the `Stream.CopyTo()` method, rather than writing your own loop.

Comment: Thanks again for the information provided :)